# 'That's how Physics work' or 'That's how Physics works'

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Do you say *'That's how physics work'* or *'That's how physics works'*?

The former one seems more intuitive and has a high chance of making it into a conversation but the latter one seems correct too. Or is it that they are both correct?

Considering you are talking about physics as discipline in the context of the latter while you're discussing the multitude of possibilities within physics in the case of the former.

Googling this made it pretty clear that native speakers use both these terms.

Comment: My own google of 'physic' showed that the majority of the answers were medical terms, while 'how physic works' appeared in poems, or as misspellings of 'psychic'.

Comment: please update title. *Edit* is disabled for me

Comment: A physic is a laxative. Physics is a scientific discipline. The former has a plural ending in *-s*; the latter is singular.

Comment: This argument rests with Webster's. Look directly below their main entry and see what it means. Are they saying it's collective or not? If it is, then it can take either a singular or plural verb. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/physics    "Physics is a science."    "The physics behind this experiment are interesting because electrical as well as mechanical energy was used to solve it."

Comment: CORRECTION: "was" should be "were" in "...electrical as well as mechanical energy were used..."

Comment: Hello Arch! You're comment is actually very helpful. So, can it be used in plural or singular form in any sentence or the connotation of that sentence is important. Like i asked in my question, does context matter here or because its a collective noun it can be used as a singular or a plural in any sentence

Comment: That may be how most physics work. But what if there is a physic that works another way?

Answer (score 4):

Speaking as a long time chemist/physicist, I know no self-respecting physicist anywhere in the world who would say, "That's how physics work." As you yourself have noted, physics is a scientific discipline and, as such, a singular noun. One should always say, "***That's how physics works***."

To support my assertion, I googled **physic** (definition), which would have to be a word in order for "That's how physics work" to make any sense. I found no references related to the discipline of **physics**.

Comment: As Sven Yargs has said: << Hello, [Richard]. Your answer seems to be [based on personal experience] as opposed to [rigorous] objective analysis—but this site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just [(semi?-)localised observation]. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do with regard to this usage. Thanks! >> However, as noted above, Reg Dwight has already provided etymological background here.

Comment: How did you google "physic"? I get results. Try [`define physic`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+physic). It has an archaic relation to physics, the discipline; see [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/physic)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's almost 4:30 AM here on the east coast of the U.S., so I'm going to have to sign off shortly. Hard to do because ELU SE is beyond addictive. A couple of points. My experiences in physics around the world over many years are not opinion -- but I grant that they are not verifiable by others. As to independent authorities, as I said in my answer, I googled "physic definition" and found no authoritative source with a definition of "physic" related to the discipline of physics. I'll check out Reg Dwight and give your comment more thought for future reference. Have a good night.

Comment: @NVZ Good to hear from you. When I searched "physic definition", all the references I found related to medicine, not physics, and many characterized even the medical meaning as archaic. So, it seems safe to say that today it would be a rare individual indeed who would use the word "physic" in connection with "physics". That said, I didn't make the matter my life's work, and nor do I intend to.

Comment: I'm not saying your conclusions are wrong. But my two degrees are in chemistry. I included references as well as observations in my MA(!) thesis, and I consider ELU to be better than a discussion forum where unsupported opinions are acceptable as answers.

Comment: @RichardKayser I agree completely. :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Point taken, but I don't consider my answer unsupported, at least not completely unsupported. I'm new to ELU though, and I still have a great deal to learn. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm going to learn how to use the Google Ngram Viewer and incorporate the results in my answers. I'll use "physic" versus "physics" as my first test case. :-)

Comment: I'd suggest that you take great care; Google Ngrams can be useful, but also need handling with kid gloves. 'That's how physics work' may be found as a parallel to 'that's how medicines work'. Reg Dwight gives reasonable references and a fine answer about how the odd -ics usages arose. Some dictionaries will point out that physics (the science) does not take plural agreement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. I'll be careful and will followup on Reg Dwight. Wiped out today.

Answer (score 0):

In British English, at least, 'physic' as a singular noun is an antique word for medicine (medicine which is taken, that is, rather than medicine as a profession). There are still people around who will say 'I need a dose of physic' when they are suffering from some minor ailment but it has rather derogatory connotations and associations with quack doctors. Physics, meaning the science of the physical properties of objects and materials, is a singular noun and as such takes the third person singular form of the verb. So "That's how physics works" is correct. By the way 'mathematics' is also a singular noun which we British shorten to 'maths' while the Americans shorten it to 'math', but both are singular so it is correct in British English to say "That's how maths works". However 'maths' can also be a plural noun, particlarly when applied to a specific problem. You will sometimes hear people say things like "The maths show that perpetual motion is impossible"

Comment: Wow! I was aware of the medical meaning of "physic" but unaware of "maths" as a word in British English, let alone "maths" as a singular noun. Bold Ben, I don't know what to say other than "Cool." :-)

Comment: Yes "physic" and "physics" have nothing more to do with each other than "physique" has to do with either.

Despite exactly the same construction, 'That's how cars work' refers collectively to several individual cars; plural use of a quantifiable, singular noun. 'That's how physics works' refers singularly - if you like comprehensively - to a concept; singular use of an unquantifiable, abstract noun.